How did Dutch know to go for a high five, not a handshake, with Dillon?
As above, how did he react in time to invert the handshake?




They seemed to be old friends, so maybe that's how they'd shaken hands in prior meetings.

Doesn’t matter much in terms of the question or the answer: that is not a high five. I’m not sure what you’d call that. A high five is when the two people put their hands at head level or higher with the palms facing towards each other and slap their palms together without gripping.

Per the script, they're old comrades and this is something of a regular greeting for them, a test of strength and a show of respect for the winner.

